# Can my code be made more efficient if I need to update pin based on a condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable AllPackages which is an array of objects. I want to get all the same Products in all objects in AllPackages and update their pin with the selectedPIN if dp.product.code matches with the object's dealProducts product's code.

```js
setProductPinOnAllPackages(dp): void {
    let AllPackages = [{"dealProducts":[{"pin":"","product":{"id":"100","code":"AAA","name":"AAA"}},{"pin":"","product":{"id":"200","code":"BBB","name":"BBB"}}]},{"dealProducts":[{"pin":"","product":{"id":"300","code":"CCC","name":"CCC"}},{"pin":"","product":{"id":"200","code":"BBB","name":"BBB"}},{"pin":"","product":{"id":"400","code":"DDD","name":"DDD"}},{"pin":"","product":{"id":"100","code":"AAA","name":"AAA"}}]}];;
    let selectedPIN = dp.pin;

    //Can this be made more efficient ????
       AllPackages.filter(pkg => pkg.dealProducts
        .filter(pkgDealProduct => pkgDealProduct.product.code === dp.product.code)
        .map(data => data.pin = selectedPIN));
}
```

Comment: "More efficient" question is likely always yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it more efficient by not constructing an unnecessary intermediate array - your goal is to perform *side-effects* (mutate the `data`), not to construct a filtered array from the `AllPackages`, so use a generic iteration method like `forEach` or `for..of` instead of `.filter` in the outer loop.

Similarly, don't use `.map`, since you aren't looking to map to a new array - again, you're looking for side-effects, so use a generic iteration method.

You can also extract the `code` from the parameter just once, instead of on every iteration.

```
const { code, pin } = dp.product;
for (const pkg of AllPackages) {
    pkg.dealProducts
        .filter(pkgDealProduct => pkgDealProduct.product.code === code)
        .forEach((data) => {
            data.pin = pin;
        });
}
```